# Why my VBA code is returning an error when I changed laptops?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA code that works perfectly. I copied the file to a new computer and now it s returning errors when running.

Same library references are added and I am using same Excel version 2016.

```
Option Explicit

Public Const firstTickerRow As Integer = 13

Sub DownloadData()

    Dim frequency As String
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim lastErrorRow As Integer
    Dim lastSuccessRow As Integer
    Dim stockTicker As String
    Dim numStockErrors As Integer
    Dim numStockSuccess As Integer
    Dim startDate As String
    Dim endDate As String
    Dim ticker As Integer
    Dim crumb As String
    Dim cookie As String
    Dim validCookieCrumb As Boolean
    Dim sortOrderComboBox As Shape
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Sheets("Analysis").Cells.ClearContents
    Sheets("Filter Stocks").Cells.ClearContents
    numStockErrors = 0
    numStockSuccess = 0
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    lastErrorRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
    lastSuccessRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
    ClearErrorList lastErrorRow
    ClearSuccessList lastSuccessRow
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
    frequency = Worksheets("Parameters").Range("b7")
    'Convert user-specified calendar dates to Unix time
    '***************************************************
    startDate = (Sheets("Parameters").Range("startDate") - DateValue("January 1, 1970")) * 86400
    endDate = (Sheets("Parameters").Range("endDate") - DateValue("January 1,     1970")) * 86400
    '***************************************************
    'Set date retrieval frequency
    '***************************************************
    If Worksheets("Parameters").Range("frequency") = "d" Then
        frequency = "1d"
    ElseIf Worksheets("Parameters").Range("frequency") = "w" Then
        frequency = "1wk"
    ElseIf Worksheets("Parameters").Range("frequency") = "m" Then
        frequency = "1mo"
    End If
    '***************************************************
    'Delete all sheets apart from Parameters sheet
    '***************************************************
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Parameters" And ws.Name <> "Stocks" And ws.Name <> "Analysis" And ws.Name <> "Filter Stocks" Then ws.Delete
    Next
    '***************************************************
    'Get cookie and crumb
    '***************************************************
    Call getCookieCrumb(crumb, cookie, validCookieCrumb)
    If validCookieCrumb = False Then
        GoTo ErrorHandler:
    End If
    '***************************************************
    'Loop through all tickers
    For ticker = firstTickerRow To lastRow
        stockTicker = Worksheets("Parameters").Range("$a$" & ticker)
        If stockTicker = "" Then
            GoTo NextIteration
        End If
        'Create a sheet for each ticker
        '***************************************************
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = stockTicker
        Cells(1, 1) = "Stock Quotes for " & stockTicker
        '***************************************************
        'Get financial data from Yahoo and write into each sheet
        'getCookieCrumb() must be run before running getYahooFinanceData()
        '***************************************************
        Call getYahooFinanceData(stockTicker, startDate, endDate, frequency, cookie, crumb)
        '***************************************************
        'Populate success or fail lists
        '***************************************************
        lastRow = Sheets(stockTicker).UsedRange.Row - 2 + Sheets(stockTicker).UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If lastRow < 3 Then
            Sheets(stockTicker).Delete
            numStockErrors = numStockErrors + 1
            ErrorList stockTicker, numStockErrors
            GoTo NextIteration
        Else
            numStockSuccess = numStockSuccess + 1
            If Left(stockTicker, 1) = "^" Then
                SuccessList Replace(stockTicker, "^", ""), numStockSuccess
            Else
                SuccessList stockTicker, numStockSuccess
            End If
        End If
        '***************************************************
        'Set the preferred date format
        '***************************************************
        Range("a3:a" & lastRow).NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd;@"
        '***************************************************
        'Sort by oldest date first or newest date first
        '***************************************************
        Set sortOrderComboBox = Sheets("Parameters").Shapes("SortOrderDropDown")
        With sortOrderComboBox.ControlFormat
            If .List(.Value) = "Oldest First" Then
                Call SortByDate(stockTicker, "oldest")
            ElseIf .List(.Value) = "Newest First" Then
                Call SortByDate(stockTicker, "newest")
            End If
        End With
        '***************************************************
        'Clean up sheet names
        '***************************************************
        'Remove initial ^ in ticker names from Sheets
        If Left(stockTicker, 1) = "^" Then
            ActiveSheet.Name = Replace(stockTicker, "^", "")
        Else
            ActiveSheet.Name = stockTicker
        End If
        'Remove hyphens in ticker names from Sheet names, otherwise error in collation
        If InStr(stockTicker, "-") > 0 Then
            ActiveSheet.Name = Replace(stockTicker, "-", "")
        End If
        '***************************************************
NextIteration:
    Next ticker
    'Process export and collation
    '***************************************************
    If Sheets("Parameters").Shapes("WriteToCSVCheckBox").ControlFormat.Value = xlOn Then
        On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:
        Call CopyToCSV
    End If
    If Sheets("Parameters").Shapes("CollateDataCheckBox").ControlFormat.Value = xlOn Then
        On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:
        Call CollateData
    End If
    '***************************************************
ErrorHandler:
    Worksheets("Parameters").Select
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Call Dynamic

End Sub

Sub SortByDate(ticker As String, order As String)

    Dim firstRow As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim sortType As Variant

    lastRow = Sheets(ticker).UsedRange.Rows.Count
    firstRow = 2
    If order = "oldest" Then
        sortType = xlAscending
    Else
        sortType = xlDescending
    End If
    Worksheets(ticker).Sort.SortFields.Clear
    Worksheets(ticker).Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Sheets(ticker).Range("A" & firstRow & ":A" & lastRow), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, order:=sortType, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ticker).Sort
        .SetRange Range("A" & firstRow & ":G" & lastRow)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

End Sub
```

The error is produced at the line `Worksheets(ticker).Sort.SortFields.Clear`:

> Error 9: Subscript out of range

I am not sure why this is occurring now.

Comment: This is not enough code to diagnose the problem exactly, but the error explains the problem: `ticker` is going out of range (reaching a value for which there is no corresponding worksheet).

Comment: What Excel is trying to tell you is that the value of the `String` variable `ticker` does not correspond to a tabname in the workbook................check the value of the variable and the names of the worksheets.

Comment: Yes I will add the full code, but the error is only happening on the new computer. The code runs with no errors on my previous machine. This why I am wondering.

Comment: '*it s returning errors*' is not an accurate description but I'm betting that one computer as VBE, Tools, Options, **Require Variable Declaration** and the other doesn't. Go with **Require Variable Declaration**. The code is broken without it.

Comment: @user10931127 The code has `Option Explicit` at the top. Whatever the problem is, that isn't it.

Comment: ... and yet you still haven't accurately described what '*it s returning errors*' actually is.

Comment: Require Variable Declaration  is selected, file saved and re-opened. This did not solve the problem. Any other suggestion please?

Comment: When I run the code, run-time error 9 occurs: Subscript out of range.
Same code works fine on my previous laptop.

Comment: ***The error is produced at the line above*** Many lines above. What line specifically?

Comment: Worksheets(ticker).sort.sortfields.clear

Comment: What is the value of `ticker` when the error occurs? And do you have a worksheet with that name?

Comment: One source of confusion is your use of `ticker`.  In one routine it is an `integer`, in another it is a `string`.  What is the value in the routine where the error occurs, when the error occurs?  And also, since you did not get that error a few lines above where your reference `Sheets(ticker)`, is it possible you are passing a Chart Sheet name vs a worksheet name?

Comment: ticker is assigned as name of new worksheet from a list in the "Parameters" sheet. As I mentioned before, the code works fine on my previous computer. This only happened when I copied the file to a new laptop.

Comment: You can restate your "assumed" cause - it doesn't work on this laptop - or you could follow a very useful suggestion - check the value of ticker when the error occurs and see if the worksheet exists. I suggest you take some steps to debug rather than restating what you think the cause is.

Comment: Hello - I have debugged the code. ticker is assigned to worksheet "AA". AA is stock symbol read from a list in one worksheet.
Worksheet AA is created and code performs some work on this sheet until it reaches the line:Worksheets(ticker).Sort.SortFields.Clear
This is when run-time error 9 occurs.

Comment: This is ridiculous. A simple single-step (F8) through the code on the new laptop will easily find the difference and cause of error. Why do you refuse to troubleshoot the proper way?

Comment: While debugging, open the immediate window. Enter these things and tell me which one gets an error 1. `? Worksheets(ticker).Name` 2. `? Sheets(ticker).Name` 3. `? ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ticker).Name`. You are referring to this sheet in _three_ different ways in this code. Any reason for that? Note that from your description, it appears that `Sheets(ticker)` works but `Worksheets(ticker)` doesn't which implies it might be a chart not a worksheet.

Comment: None of the lines you mentioned give an error at all. They all returned "AA" as expected/

Error again occurs at this line Worksheets(ticker).Sort.SortFields.Clear 

I know I have been repeating myself, but code works fine on my previous machine. It's confusing.

Comment: Well the logical thing to do is now move towards the offending code. We can assume that if you type Worksheets(ticker).Sort.SortFields.Clear` into the immediate window it's going to fail? and based on your test, `Worksheets(ticker)` is fine. So it's something to do with `.Sort` or `.Sort.SortFields`. There's no way in this forum to work out what the difference between laptops is.